# How to clear the json object written by APEX_JSON

Tags: json, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I am new to ORDS. I am using APEX_JSON to create a json object for one of my rest services with source type as PL/SQL.
The json object that i am creating is complex.
If any thing fails while creating the json object then I have to return an error which has different json structure in the body.
So before creating the body for error I want to clear the json that I have created till this point.
How can I do this. Or are there any other ways to achieve this.

```
PROCEDURE GETNODES(I_LOCATION IN NUMBER)
V_STATUS NUMBER;
BEGIN
    APEX_JSON.OPEN_OBJECT;
    APEX_JSON.OPEN_ARRAY('NODES');

    FOR nodes in (select NAME FROM NODES where location = I_LOCATION) LOOP
        APEX_JSON.OPEN_OBJECT;
        APEX_JSON.write('NAME',nodes.name);
        V_STATUS := getnodestatus(nodes.name); --This can throw an exception
        APEX_JSON.write('STATUS',V_STATUS);
        APEX_JSON.CLOSE_OBJECT;
    END LOOP;

    APEX_JSON.CLOSE_ARRAY;
    APEX_JSON.CLOSE_OBJECT;

EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
--IF I get any error, then I have to write a different json, so I have to clear the json written till now, how to do it?
    APEX_JSON.OPEN_OBJECT;
    APEX_JSON.write('ERROR CODE',SQLCODE);
    APEX_JSON.write('ERROR MSG',SQLERRM);
    APEX_JSON.CLOSE_OBJECT;
END;
```

PS: The above code is just for an example. The JSON object that I am writing inside the loop is much more complex with multiple levels of arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

APEX_JSON can write to a temporary CLOB, rather than pushing output through the gateway, as explained here.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
  l_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN

  OPEN l_cursor FOR
    SELECT e.empno AS "employee_number",
           e.ename AS "employee_name",
           e.deptno AS "department_number"
    FROM   emp e
    WHERE  rownum <= 2;

  APEX_JSON.initialize_clob_output;

  APEX_JSON.open_object;
  APEX_JSON.write('employees', l_cursor);
  APEX_JSON.close_object;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(APEX_JSON.get_clob_output);
  APEX_JSON.free_output;
END;
/
```

As explained here:
https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/apex_json-package-generate-and-parse-json-documents-in-oracle#temporary-clob

Write your JSON to the CLOB. If it works, push it out to the gateway using HTP.print. If it fails send out your error message.

Cheers

Tim...

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim, It worked.

But in this way I had to set the content-type (mime type) to json manually by calling 'owa_util.mime_header('application/json')'. By default it was set to 'text/html'. 
Is this the correct way or is there any other way?

Comment: That's fine. Also remember to deal with large CLOBs properly. You might need to push it out over the gateway in chunks if it's bigger than 32K. https://oracle-base.com/dba/script?category=miscellaneous&file=string_api.sql